# document.getElementById doesn't work in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing

I get an error("myDiv is null"), when I try to use `document.getElementById` in Cypress. Can anybody give me a hint? This is my setup:

```js
a.html
...
<div id='myid'>
</div>
...

test.cy.js

function foo()
{
    let myDiv = document.getElementById('myid');
    let myParagraphs = myDiv.getElementsByTagName('p');
    ...
}


it('MyTest', ()=>   {
        cy.visit('\fsdgjfs\a.html');
        foo();
        ...
        
});
```

myDiv should be not null.

Comment: I strongly suspect that your `cy.visit()` call is not working the way you expect.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `document` instead of the built in Cypress commands such as `cy.get()`? Mixing async code (such as Cypress commands) and synchronous code (such as document.getElementById()` can often lead to unexpected behaviors. I agree with @Pointy -> I think your `foo()` command (sync) is firing before your `cy.visit()` command (async).

Comment: First I have to I find out wheter the element mydiv>p exists. If this element doesn't exist foo should return immediately.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find out if `mydiv > p` exists, the best way is to use [cypress-if](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-if) plugin.

That way you can use Cypress command with full timeout/retry, but branch the test code if your element does or does not exist.

**Install**

```js
$ npm i -D cypress-if
# or using Yarn
$ yarn add -D cypress-if
```

**Import in /cypress/support/e2e.js**

```js
import 'cypress-if'
```

**Test**

```js
it('MyTest', ()=> {
  cy.visit('\');
  cy.get('#myid > p')
    .if()
    .log('exists')
    ...                      // commands when exists
    .else()
    .log('does not exist')
    ...                      // commands when not exists
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing synchronous and asynchronous commands, and it is causing your `foo()` command to fire before `cy.visit()` is fired (or completes).

Consider the following two code samples:

```js
it('test', () => {
  cy.visit('https://www.google.com');
  const googleDocument = document;
  expect(googleDocument).to.not.be.null;
});

it('test', () => {
  cy.visit('https://www.google.com')
  .then(() => {
    const googleDocument = document;
    expect(googleDocument).to.not.be.null;
  });
});
```

The first test will fail, because the `googleDocument` variable is declared synchronously, before the `cy.visit` command completes.
The second test will pass, because the `googleDocument` variable is declared inside of an asynchronous `cy.then()` block, which occurs only *after* `cy.visit()` completes.